# Comparing String with equals

Tags: java, string

```
String site_inclusion = "0;100";

for (String inc: site_inclusion.split(";")) {
   if(!inc.equals(String.valueOf(record.getAttrs().get(new PdsxAttrKey("SiteId")).getValue()))) {
      continue;         
   }
}
```

And `record.getAttrs().get(new PdsxAttrKey("SiteId")).getValue()` returns `77`

So from my code it should be going to `continue` block right? But it is not going to continue?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ughh ... I'm not going to try to read that code.  It makes my head hurt.  It is screaming "Refactor Me! Refactor Me!".  And I just heard "Coding Conventions! Coding Conventions!" too.

Comment: It is already in refactored I guess.

Comment: and remember to post in questions SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Comment: The other problem is that you've obviously cobbled together this code from something else ... and left out some important details in the process.  Like what type of object is returned by record.getAttrs().get(new PdsxAttrKey("SiteId"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you simplify your code to test what's going on. You might have made a mistake trying to build an example.

```
String site_inclusion = "0;100";

for (String inc: site_inclusion.split(";")) {
    String temp = String.valueOf(record.getAttrs().get(new PdsxAttrKey("SiteId")).getValue());
    if(!inc.equals(temp)) {
        System.out.println(inc + " != " + temp);
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(inc + " == " + temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to check what are the variables (System.out.println/debugging).
The reason why it's not going in that way you think is for sure that condition in `if` statement.

Try splitting your code into smaller pieces.

```
String site_inclusion = "0;100";
            for(String inc : site_inclusion.split(";")) {
                int value = record.getAttrs().get(new PdsxAttrKey("SiteId")).getValue();
                System.out.println("Inc = " + inc + " and value = " + value);
                if(!inc.equals(String.valueOf(value))) {
                    System.out.println("continue");
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(inc + " equals " + value);
            }
```